# Table css for mobile email template

Tags: html, css, html-table

I use need to show payment summary of purchased vouchers,so I write:

```
<div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="m_8020711154386302143pe-data-table-con m_8020711154386302143k-state-active">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#f1f1f1" bgcolor="#f1f1f1" dir="ltr" class="m_8020711154386302143pe-data-table m_8020711154386302143k-table">
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($bvouchers as $voucher)
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:bold">
                  {{$voucher->qty}} x {{$voucher->name}}
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:normal">
                  £{{$voucher->total}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
              @if ($order->user->type == 2)
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:bold">
                  Subtotal:
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:normal">
                  £ {{$bvouchers->sum('total')-$bvouchers->sum('total')/100*$bvouchers->first()->user->vatrate}}
                </td>
              </tr>    
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:bold">
                  VAT total ({{$order->user->vatrate}}%)
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:normal">
                  £{{$bvouchers->sum('total')/100*$bvouchers->first()->user->vatrate}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:bold">
                  TOTAL
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:normal">
                  £ {{$bvouchers->sum('total')}}
                </td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:bold">
                  Supplied by; {{$order->user->restaurant}}, VAT no. {{$order->user->vat}}
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" style="text-align:left;color:#333333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;margin:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;font-weight:normal">
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endif
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and works well on desktop (gmail) email client but on mobile second column in row show value like:

$

1

1

0

How to solve that... I try different ways but always is the same... width of second column in row is like 1%...

Comment: Can you try to add <colgroup> and <col? in <tbody> and check again?

Comment: colgroup instead what? can you show me example ?